# enumerateSubstringsInRange in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

Am Rewriting my existing objective c code(ios) to Swift, facing some issues with enumerateSubstringsInRange method.. Can any one help me to convert following code to Swift?

```
[contentString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[contentString length])
                               options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                               usingBlock: ^(NSString *substring,
                               NSRange substringRange, 
                               NSRange enclosingRange,BOOL *stop) {

          if(substring.length >= 2) {
              /* my code goes here */
          }
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of that code? Swift strings handle Unicode characters much better than NSStrings, so there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
contentString.enumerateSubstringsInRange(NSMakeRange(0, (contentString as NSString).length), options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByComposedCharacterSequences) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
    if((substring as NSString).length >= 2) {
        NSLog("%@", substring)
    } 
}
```

**Note** that in order to access the length property of a `String` you have to cast it to a `NSString`, as seen above.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift Version 3.0.2, Use the following code

```
         string.enumerateSubstrings(in: NSMakeRange(0, (string as NSString).length), options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byComposedCharacterSequences) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in

        let objCString:NSString = NSString(string:substring!)
        let hs: unichar = objCString.character(at: 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
       contentString.enumerateSubstrings(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: contentString.length), options: NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences, usingBlock: {(_ substring: String, _ substringRange: NSRange, _ enclosingRange: NSRange, _ stop: Bool) -> Void in
        if substring.length >= 2 {
            /* my code goes here */
        }
    })
```

For more, you can go here to convert your number of codes online. https://iswift.org/try. Hope this help.

Comment: Above is not mentioned Swift 3, i guess. Edited for Swift 3.

Comment: My bad, the tag has been added after you answered.

Answer (score -1):

let contentString:NSString = "string";

contentString.enumerateSubstrings(in: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: contentString.length), options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byComposedCharacterSequences) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange,
            stop) in
            //your code
        }

Comment: While this answer could be correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem.